# Assembly binding redirect from a Class Library

Tags: visual-studio, .net-assembly, assembly-binding-redirect, assemblybinding

I have a GitHub project ([Test Automation Essentials](https://github.com/arnonax/TestEssentials)) which references some Visual Studio specific assemblies (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension` which is part of CodedUI; but that's not significant for the question). This project is published as a NuGet package containing my class library.

I want my project to support different versions of Visual Studio, and all in all, this assembly does not have any noticeable differences between the versions of Visual Studio, so I don't anticipate any compatibility issues (it should be backward compatible anyway).

However, if I compile my project in one version of Visual Studio (e.g. 2015), when I try to reference the NuGet package from a project in a newer version of Visual Studio (e.g. 2017), when the hosting project runs I get the following exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
```

Note: my library references this assembly with `Specific Version=False`.

I found I can work around this issue by adding the following element to the `app.config` of the application:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="12.0.0.0-15.0.0.0"  newVersion="15.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Note: In this particular case the executable is typically `QTAgent32_40.exe` which is itself part of Visual Studio, so I had to add the element to `QTAgent32_40.exe.config` and not actually to the project's `app.config` file. `QTAgent32_40.exe.config` already has many similar `dependentAssembly` elements, but for some reason not for this specific assembly.

**The question:**

I don't want my clients to add this setting themselves. I'd be glad if I could have such a setting specific for *my class library*, so that anyone who references my library automatically gets this Assembly Redirect setting. However, I didn't find a way to do that...

Does anyone knows how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to create a Nuget package for each specific version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do it without duplicating the csproj for each version?

Comment: You could have multiple build configs of the same project.

Comment: You can write selective references in msbuild using the choose/when construct and when you use visual studio 15.6+ you can also include selective packageReference items to reference specific nuget packages and/or package versions. You can find an example implemented here https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator